# libGLEW.so.1.9: cannot open shared object file. no such file or directory

Tags: bash, glew

I am trying to run an application that I made -that uses glew.
It compiles fine, but when I try to run it, I get the error: libGLEW.so.1.9: cannot open shared object file. no such file or directory. I've checked to see if I have it, and it's in usr/lib64.
I've tried other fixes on the internet, and I edited the /etc/ld.so.conf to this:

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf /usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.1.9(adding this second path)
```

and then ran ldconfig, but the terminal spat out a whole lot of gibberish.

Can someone please help?
    btw, sorry about the uninformative title.

Comment: In general, this is something your OS distro should take care of for you (if you're using its package manager for all installations). Random pages on the Internet notwithstanding, if you're needing to change the dynamic linker's configuration or update its cache by hand but you didn't install something by hand, something's broken.

Comment: Also, this is really a system administration question rather than a programming question [and thus may go better on Super User than Stack Overflow], and particularly not a bash question (ld.so ships with glibc, not bash).

Comment: I had to install glew manually, because apt repositories only have up to glew 1.6. I need 1.9

Comment: ...hopefully, you didn't just "install" someone else's binaries, but actually compiled them against your local system?

Comment: No, I just did what the glew download page told me to do haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple fault.

Instead of adding the path to specifically include

```
/usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.1.9
```

in the `ld.so.config` file, I tried just including the path

```
/usr/lib64/
```

Comment: You didn't mean to include those last three dots, did you?

Answer (score 5):

You should read `man ldconfig`:

> DESCRIPTION

```
     ldconfig creates the necessary links  and  cache  to  the  most  recent
     shared  libraries  found  in  the  directories specified on the command
     line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/lib
     and  /usr/lib).  The cache is used by the run-time linker, ld.so or ld-
     linux.so.  ldconfig checks the header and filenames of the libraries it
     encounters  when  determining  which  versions  should have their links
     updated.
```

That file should be auto-generated. On Gentoo, it contains only directories.

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf
# ld.so.conf autogenerated by env-update; make all changes to
# contents of /etc/env.d directory
/lib64
/usr/lib64
/usr/local/lib64
/lib32
/usr/lib32
/usr/local/lib32
/lib
/usr/lib
/usr/local/lib
include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/lib32/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia
/usr/lib64/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia
/usr/lib32/opengl/nvidia/lib
/usr/lib64/opengl/nvidia/lib
/usr/lib64/qca2
/usr/lib64/qt4
/usr/lib32/qt4
/usr/lib/qt4
/usr/lib/postgresql
/usr/lib64/postgresql
/usr/lib64/postgresql-9.3/lib64/
/usr/games/lib64
/usr/games/lib32
/usr/games/lib
```

Looking at /etc/env.d ...

```
$ grep LD /etc/env.d/*
/etc/env.d/00basic:LDPATH='/lib64:/usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib64:/lib32:/usr/lib32:/usr/local/lib32:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib'
/etc/env.d/00glibc:LDPATH="include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf"
/etc/env.d/03opencl:LDPATH="/usr/lib32/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia:/usr/lib64/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia"
/etc/env.d/03opengl:LDPATH="/usr/lib32/opengl/nvidia/lib:/usr/lib64/opengl/nvidia/lib"
/etc/env.d/44qca2:LDPATH="/usr/lib64/qca2"
/etc/env.d/44qt4:LDPATH="/usr/lib64/qt4:/usr/lib32/qt4:/usr/lib/qt4"
/etc/env.d/44qt4-emul:LDPATH=/usr/lib32/qt4
/etc/env.d/50postgresql:LDPATH="/usr/lib/postgresql:/usr/lib64/postgresql:/usr/lib64/postgresql-9.3/lib64/"
/etc/env.d/90games:LDPATH="/usr/games/lib64:/usr/games/lib32:/usr/games/lib"
```

Judging by what I see you should examine the files in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/, copy one of them into a new file such as glew.conf, and modify the path within the new file to point to  the folder where the lib file is.